# Java Webservices using jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>WS</display-name>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sayhello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
    </servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sayhello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
    <endpoint
            name="MyWsEndpoint"
            implementation="com.test.ws.MyWsEndpoint"
            url-pattern="/ws"/>
</endpoints>
```

MyWsEndpoint.java

```
package com.test.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://my.ws/MyWs",
        portName = "MyWsService",
        serviceName = "MyWs",
        endpointInterface = "com.test.ws.MyWsService")

public class MyWsEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements MyWsService {

    @Autowired
    private MyWsService proxy;


    @Override
      @WebMethod()
    public String getName(String name) {
        String a=proxy.getName("John");
        return a;
    }

}
```

MyWsService.java

```
package com.test.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public interface MyWsService {
    public String getName(String name);
}
```

HelloImpl.java

```
package com.test.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.test.ws.MyWsService")
public class HelloImpl implements  MyWsService{

    @Override
    public String getName(String name) {
        String s=name;
        return s;
    }

}
```

I am getting null pointer exception in soap :-

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Can anyone try to run this code and tell me my mistakes? Need to add few jax-ws jars in lib to run the code.

I have followed a few online tutorials on how to deploy a JAX-WS web service in Tomcat. I have created a web service class and annotated it with @WebService, written a web.xml and sun-jaxws.xml file, packaged those files (plus the JAX-WS jar files) into a .war file, and deployed it into Tomcat. That appears to be working, as I can load the WSDL file in a browser pointed at Tomcat.